# How can I access the DOM of another HTML page, to test DOM manipulation functions from QUnit

Tags: javascript, html, unit-testing, dom, qunit

I am writing test cases in QUNIT for a JavaScript project. I have already tested functions which return a value.

But there are functions in the codebase which access the DOM and do stuff with it. I want to access the DOM of the HTML pages that are changed by these functions, so that I can check they're working.

I tried `document.url` as well as `window.open` but when I try to to do `document.getElementByTagName("script")` on that page It gives me `null`. Which means I am not able to access the other page's DOM.

Comment: So 2 pages are opened simultaneously? Like in 2 different windows or tabs?

Comment: Note that, in browsers, JavaScript DOM manipulations of an HTML page only last as long as that HTML page is open in a browser window. I don't understand exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Do you want to do this on the server side or client side? and how about using AJAX?

Comment: @Yuriy Galanter.Anything would work as long as the html is not included in my page(hence won't render) and I am able to access its dom from my javascript in my html Page.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite so I am writing test cases in QUNIT for a javascript project.So as of now I am done with functions which return a value and are basic functions like parseQueryParams and all.But there are functions in the codebase which access the DOM and do stuff with it.So how would I test those cases since I dont have access to the DOM the main code function is trying to access.Thats what I am trying to acheive.

Comment: @MarcAudet I want to this on client side because I want to test javascript functions using QUnit.U can suugest me any server side process as well which can test functions which manipulate and work with DOM.One more thing the code doesnt access the database in anywhich way.No Read/Write.

Comment: @SwarajChhatre: thanks, those details make your question comprehensible. I've edited it to reflect what you're trying to do, including tagging it with QUnit. I don't have any experience with QUnit, so I can't answer your question, but I'm sure other people have come across the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

One idea is to load the other page in an iframe. You can then use window.parent to access the parent page from the iframe.

Comment: Thanks @TGH.But the thing is that I am writing test cases using QUNIT in my html page so I cannot render a new html page in an iframe from my html page because my html page has to show the test results and adding an iframe page with a html src will not make sense since I have to just access it and not show in my DOM.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial has a good starting point reference to DOM testing..

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/27/introduction-to-javascript-unit-testing/

Comment: Hey too late for the answer.I am done with the project.Thanks neways.

Comment: No problem. The beauty of stack overflow is it's never too late for an answer. The potential answer to someone else's problem will already be waiting here for them.